# Is this neural network architecture appropriate for CIFAR-10?

Tags: neural-networks, convolutional-neural-networks, tensorflow

I have a CNN architecture for CIFAR-10 dataset which is as follows:

> Convolutions:           64, 64, pool
>
> Fully Connected Layers: 256, 256, 10
>
> Batch size:             60
>
> Optimizer:              Adam(2e-4)
>
> Loss:                   Categorical Cross-Entropy

When I train this model, training and testing accuracy along with loss has a very jittery behavior and does not converge properly.

Is the defined architecture correct? Should I have a max-pooling layer after every convolution layer?

Comment: I know this is an old question, but could you please edit it to include the result of [`plot_model(your_model_object)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/plot_model)? Moreover, you should provide the plots that show the behavior of the accuracy and loss. You should explain for how long you have been training.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, your model is not very clear. But basically after the convolution, you need to add non-linear layers. Otherwise, there is no point of Neural Networks.

You can add a Relu layer for sure.

Comment: I am using TensorFlow 2.0 Conv2D layer and I am using ReLU activation function